# How to create relationship to the same entity with JPA (Hibernate)?

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa, orm

I have an entity `User` and it should have property `manager` where manager is another user (one manager can manage many users, any user may have only 1 manager or have not any).

How can I implement this?

I tried something standard

```
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn (name = ??? /* what should be here? */, nullable = true)
private User manager;
```

but it's not as simple as it seems..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What's the problem? Use the default value i.e. don't set the `name` if you don't know how to name the join column (should default to something like MANAGER_ID). From the javadoc of the [`name`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/5/api/javax/persistence/JoinColumn.html#name%28%29) attribute:

> (Optional) **The name of the foreign key
>   column**. The table in which it is found
>   depends upon the context. **If the join
>   is for a OneToOne or Many- ToOne
>   mapping, the foreign key column is in
>   the table of the source entity**. If the
>   join is for a ManyToMany, the foreign
>   key is in a join table. Default (only
>   applies if a single join column is
>   used): The concatenation of the
>   following: the name of the referencing
>   relationship property or field of the
>   referencing entity; "_"; the name of
>   the referenced primary key column. If
>   there is no such referencing
>   relationship property or field in the
>   entity, the join column name is formed
>   as the concatenation of the following:
>   the name of the entity; "_"; the name
>   of the referenced primary key column.

Answer (score 4):

This should work:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name="manager")
private User manager;
```

Answer (score 0):

you should put the name of the column which you want to join to your `User` entity.  The name can be anything you want, its how it will appear in your database.  `"manager_id"` or whatever.