# hibernate annotations same class reference

Tags: java, hibernate, hibernate-annotations

I'm in need of help with hibernate annotation, when I have a table with same parent id.

Like this example

```
CREATE TABLE `server` (
  `server` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(20) DEFAULT NULL,
  `parentid` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `parentid` (`parentid`),
  KEY `server` (`server`),
  CONSTRAINT `server_fk` FOREIGN KEY (`parentid`) REFERENCES `server` (`server`)
);
```

Output like this

```
Server A
    Server B
        Server C
        Server D
    Server E
        Server C
        Server D
    Server F
    Server G
```

How can I map this in my Class

```
@Entity
public class Server {
    @Id @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    private String name, description;

    private Server parentid;

}
```

Comment: Try this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300263/how-to-create-relationship-to-the-same-entity-with-jpa-hibernate) from SO whichi is basically the same thing with "User" entities

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to create relationship to the same entity with JPA (Hibernate)?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3300263/how-to-create-relationship-to-the-same-entity-with-jpa-hibernate)